# The information is not displayed after the first load of the page, only after rerendering the second time. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx, pageload

The information from openweathermap API is not displayed after the first load of the page, only after rerendering the second time. I can't understand why.

```
const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState('')
const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState('')

const [data, setData] = useState({})
const [location, setLocation] = useState('')

const metric_units = 'metric'
const API_KEY = '5bb165082febcb3965e5bded762c5711'
const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&q=${location}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=${metric_units}`

// Gets users location from API by latitude and longitude
useEffect(() => {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      setLatitude(position.coords.latitude)
      setLongitude(position.coords.longitude)

      axios.get(API_URL).then((response) => {
        setData(response.data)
        setMyLocation(response.data.name)
        setLocation(myLocation)
      })
    })
 } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Where is `navigator.geolocation` coming from?

Comment: From Geolocation API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but in my perspective you would change your code like the below

```
useEffect(() => {
navigator.geolocation &&
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    setApiUrl(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&q=${location}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=${metric_units}`
    );});}, []);
```

Now the first render set Lat & Long and now another useEffect fetch data like the blow

```
 useEffect(() => {
axios.get(apiUrl).then((response) => {
  setData(response.data);
  setMyLocation(response.data.name);
  setLocation(myLocation);
});}, [apiUrl]);
```

Becuase the first useEffect will work at the first render and create your apiUrl and followed by setting a new apiUrl the second useEffect would be render again to fecth data.
Please let me know if you try it.